# Can we change the Font text & color for our modern SharePoint online UI

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, modern-experience, theme

I am starting a new SharePoint online project, and the first requirement that came in is to build a POC site for the customer, but they want to define a custom Fonts and Colors for the site to meet their standards.. so is this possible inside SharePoint modern UI ? to define custom fonts and Colors other than the build-in features provided by the Sitting>> Change the Look.. which does have a coloring options but does not have any options to change the font.

Thanks

Comment: My answer doesn't work for you ? I tested multiple times and it's working fine

Comment: John. If possible, avoid changing the fonts. If your company or clients ask for it - try to push back. We tried changing fonts before and you will start all sorts of issues. For example, there are icon fonts you will break. You will also break the text editor webpart's fonts and a lot of other places. Instead, simply list to the clients the official supported customizations. For example, custom themes.

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov this is sound like a wise advice .. thank you..

Answer (score 3):

Well I have faced that situation months ago where I had to apply some branding things for SharePoint Online modern pages. So here is my results from my investigations (which I already applied and it's working fine)

- First of all, You need to know that Microsoft doesn't support
  injecting or adding alternate CSS or JS or any other OOTB way to
  apply some custom styling in SPO
- Even using classic themes in mdern pages doesn't change the font and the color palette.
- So if you want to brand your site with your personalized specific font and styles you need to **Create a customised theme**

---

### COLOR PALETTE

---

To do this, you can use the following steps :

1. **First step :** Using [The Theme Generator](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/styles/web) offered by Microsoft, start creating your suitable font and color combination. Once you are done copy the output generated in the "Output" page and choose "PowerShell"

[image]

1. **Second step :** using the following PowerShell script, and having the required admin permissions this code will get the job done :

***Here fill the information about your tenant***

```
$adminUPN="admin@yourorganization.onmicrosoft.com"
$orgName="yourorganization"
$userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Type the password."
Connect-SPOService -Url https://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $userCredential
```

***Themepalette gotten from Theme Generator***

```
$themepalette = @{
"themePrimary" = "#0078d4";
"themeLighterAlt" = "#eff6fc";
"themeLighter" = "#deecf9";
"themeLight" = "#c7e0f4";
"themeTertiary" = "#71afe5";
"themeSecondary" = "#2b88d8";
"themeDarkAlt" = "#106ebe";
"themeDark" = "#005a9e";
"themeDarker" = "#004578";
"neutralLighterAlt" = "#f8f8f8";
"neutralLighter" = "#f4f4f4";
"neutralLight" = "#eaeaea";
"neutralQuaternaryAlt" = "#dadada";
"neutralQuaternary" = "#d0d0d0";
"neutralTertiaryAlt" = "#c8c8c8";
"neutralTertiary" = "#c2c2c2";
"neutralSecondary" = "#858585";
"neutralPrimaryAlt" = "#4b4b4b";
"neutralPrimary" = "#333333";
"neutralDark" = "#272727";
"black" = "#1d1d1d";
"white" = "#ffffff";
}
```

***Add the theme to SharePoint Online***

```
Add-SPOTheme -Identity "Custom-Theme" -Palette $themepalette -IsInverted $false
```

3. **Third step :** Now go to your SharePoint site and apply the new theme

***MORE DETAILS*** : https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-configure-and-apply-a-custom-theme-in-sharepoint-online/

---

### Font & Typography

---

***SharePoint Framework Extension Application Customizer*** is your solution

Using it, you can inject custom css to SP modern pages and luckily Microsoft already listed that on the official documentation (I hope you have some experience using SPFx because it's required)

1. **First step :** Download your font and copy it to your SPFx extension project using the following code

   @import ‘https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans|PT+Sans+Caption|PT+Sans+Narrow’;
2. **Second step :** use this in your application customizer SCSS file

Then you can use the font like:
font-family: ‘PT Sans Caption’, sans-serif;

3. **Third step :** use the CSS Selectors to find out the areas where you want to change the font style and apply your CSS customisation :

   font-size: 40pt;
   color: orangered;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
4. **Fourth step :** Debug and test your code
5. **Fivth step :** Deploy it (depending on your need, you can choose the level where this customisation should be deployed "tenant, site collection or any level)

You can check here ([SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/react-application-injectcss)) for more details

**Please accept the answer if it works.**

Comment: thanks a lot for the helpful reply.. but can you advice more on how i can use the Theme generator @ https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/styles/web? second question, you mentioned that injecting custom CSS is not supported while in your  approach to apply custom "Font & Typography" you are injecting custom CSS.. so does this mean that your approach for applying custom "Font & Typography" is not supported by Microsoft? thanks

Comment: For the first question, I expect that you will ask this one, well check here SharePoint Maven has already make full details of that 
https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-configure-and-apply-a-custom-theme-in-sharepoint-online/

Comment: For the second question, what I meant in first place you cannot inject cusom css in "Code Snippet" OOTB SharePoint WebPart, this is why you need to develop your own one with SPFx and deploy it as a package on your app catalog

Comment: thanks for your reply ..so you mean injecting custom CSS using SPFX web part is supported? what if Microsoft apply an update and changed the CSS markup, then the injected CSS might stop working or might cause issues.. am i correct?

Comment: It depends on your type of customisation, however most of time MS Updates will still work for your SPFx packages

Comment: but in the example you gave for "Font & Typography" customization, you mentioned that i need to use CSS Selectors to find out the areas where I want to change the font.. and those areas will be either CSS ids or CSS classes.. and those might get changed by Microsoft, so the customization will stop working, or might cause issues in extreme scenarios..  even if i am defining those customization inside SPFX.. am i correct?

Comment: What you have said is right, however changing the id and classes of the HTML elements in an Official Microsoft Service is so rare, you can count on that

Comment: Any luck with that ? it still 23 hours I hope you get the things done

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to create a new theme. Color palette and fonts.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/color-palettes-and-fonts-in-sharepoint

You will need to export the theme, change it, then import it again.

https://pixelmill.com/changing-colors-modern-site/

> In Powershell, run this:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com
```

Enter your central admin credentials.

```
Get-SPOHideDefaultThemes
```

Now, define a variable and assign the JSON to it:

> $themepalette = [paste the code here]

Next, run the Add-SPOTheme commandlet:
Add-SPOTheme

> -Name "Your Theme Name" -Palette $themepalette -IsInverted $false T

You can access it from the “Change the look” panel.

This will only change colors, not fonts in modern pages. If you want to change fonts, you'll need to follow the link from the above url and do css injection.

Here's the project:

https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/react-application-injectcss

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but have u tried this approach before? and is it recommended by Microsoft?

Comment: @johnGu I have tried it and I have done it before. It is the only way to put custom colors and fonts Online. It requires some development and can't be done out of the box. Previously, you could just upload master page using css, but Online is a bit more stringent about that. Some sharepoint links that could help you in your task: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53519.sharepoint-layouts-path-urls-quick-references.aspx

Comment: so will this approach allow us to change the default fonts ? or it is mainly used for changing the color?

Comment: You can change both fonts and colors by making a custom theme and site template. It is mostly used to change colors, though, but it is a recommended way to change the fonts on the whole site.

Comment: ok thanks will try this and let you know if i face any issues

Comment: Ok, accept the answer if it works.

Comment: i tried your approach and i can only change the colors for the theme, while i am unable to change the font size,family and color... am i correct?

Comment: @johnGu you are correct. I was forced to use spfx extension to make it work by injecting custom css. It appears that themes have stopped working that way on modern pages, even if you edit them just right.

Comment: but doing CSS injection is not supported by Microsoft as per my knowledge.. mainly because the markup you are customizing (either CSS classes or ids) might get changed by Microsoft...

Comment: @johnGu I know. But that's the only way to do it. In the end, I did it by targeting the classes in the widest possible way, like:  [class*="title-"] etc

Comment: so can you edit your original question,, mentioning that you r approach can only change the colors not the fonts , which i were asking to achieve ? thanks

Comment: @johnGu ok, did it.